# Subversion user management with LDAP and local users

Tags: svn, configuration

I'm looking for a (graphical/web) tool that allows configuration of the users that are allowed to access a subversion repository.

Our admins don't want to add every single user manually, so I'm wondering if there is a tool that allows configuration for LDAP groups/users and to add local users. I already found [SUAFE](http://code.google.com/p/suafe/), but that is only for local users.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Submerged?
http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/subversion-with-apache-and-ldap-updated.html

You can use the PHP LDAP and use User-friendly SVN (web interface) for easier administration. 
http://www.usvn.info/

Comment: usvn looks nice, I will install a demonstration and test it.